# Как в цикле обойти все контролы определенного типа?

Tags: delphi

Надо присвоить множеству компонентов TEdit значение:

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
  Edit{i}.text:='...'; // Вместо {i} номер, типа Edit1, Edit2, ...
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Добавлю. Делать циклическую обработку группы компонентов опираясь на `Name` - плохая практика. Завтра захочется дать своим компонентам осмысленные имена (Edit_Nаme, Edit_Note, Edit_Address и т.п.) и алгоритм сломается. Для циклической обработки лучше опираться на Parent (контейнер в котором находится компонент), или Owner (если нужно обработать все компоненты формы), или Tag с кастомным значением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все сравнительно просто. Если закрыть глаза на возможные ошибки, то код будет выглядеть так

```
for i := 1 to 10 do
  TEdit(FindComponent('Edit'+IntToStr(i))).Text := '...';
```

Более корректный вариант такой

```
var e:TEdit;
    s:string;
    i:integer;
begin
  for i:=1 to 10 do begin
    s := 'Edit1'+IntToStr(i);
    e := TEdit(FindComponent(s));
    if e <> nil then
      e.text := '...'
    else
      ShowMessage('Не могу найти ' + s);
  end;
end;
```

Хотите больше - читайте [тут](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1048).

Answer (score 4):

Не так просто...

```
for i := 0 to 10 do
  for j := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
    if (Component[j] is TEdit) and SameText(Component[j].Name, 'Edit' + IntToStr(i)) then
    begin
      TEdit(Component[j]).Text = '...';
      Break;
    end;
```

Comment: обьясните пожалуйста, что за оператор Component[]

Comment: Костыль, но плюс)

Comment: Break;
а что этот делает?

Comment: @KiTE код может не работать в одном случае. Если имя компонента будет написано с маленькой буквы:)
Код с квадратичной сложностью!

Comment: Да, согласен. Но, судя по названиям компонентов, они были добавлены из палитры без последующих изменений. А, по-дефолту, для TEdit-а название компонента будет с большой буквы. Да и смысл ответа по большей части в том, чтобы показать принцип обращения к группе компонентов.

На счет квадратичной сложности, тоже согласен. Но, если не вдаваться в детали, `FindComponent()` делает такой же циклический проход по всему списку. Так что выгода от его использования только в компактности кода.

Comment: В данном случае - да, скорее всего имя будет Edit*, но помните, что Ваш код могут увидеть другие. Пишете набросок - хотя бы уточните когда Ваш код будет работать.

Comment: @KoVadim, согласен, исправил.

Comment: SameText(Component[j].Name, 'Edit' + IntToStr(i))
заменить на
(CompateText(Component[j].Name, Format('Edit%d',[i])=0)
и будет работать независимо от регистра

Comment: `SameText()` - это, и так, нечувствительное к регистру сравнение.